# Does the 2-category of topoi have exponential objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory

Does the 2-category of Grothendieck topoi have exponential objects?

There are size issues: Since Grothendieck topoi are supposed to have a small set of generators, the collection of objects of a Grothendieck topos has to be a *class* and cannot be a [conglomerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conglomerate_(mathematics)). However, classes (in contrast to conglomerates) don't have nice closure properties: if $A$ and $B$ are classes, then the conglomerate $B^A$ is, in general, *not* a class.

So for the purposes of my question, drop the small set of generators from the Giraud axioms. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. [Some, but not all topoi are exponentiable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponentiable+topos).

Comment: Thanks! When speaking of exponentiable toposes, does the nLab use the convention of dropping the small set of generators from Giraud's axioms as well? Otherwise I guess no large Grothendieck topos can be exponentiable.

Comment: @user1009651 No, the nlab is talking about Grothendieck toposes in the usual sense. The categorical product of Grothendieck toposes is not the same as the product of the underlying categories (in fact, the product of underlying categories is the _coproduct_ in the 2-category of Grothendieck toposes and geometric morphisms), and the exponential $\mathcal F^{\mathcal E}$, when it exists, does not agree with the functor category or even the category of geometric morphisms from $\mathcal E$ to $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Whoops, right, what I really intended to ask was about possible right adjoints of $\mathcal E+-$, then. Do you have any idea concerning that?

Comment: The functor E+ fails to preserve the initial object (unless E is the initial topos itself) so it doesn’t have a right adjoint.

Comment: Thanks, Tim Campion!

Comment: Is there any situation in topos theory in which dropping the small set of generators from Giraud's axioms is relevant, as I argued in the question? To me it feels not so nice that Grothendieck topoi are forced to be classes (and not conglomerates), because classes don't have nice closure properties.

Comment: @user1009651 If you drop the small generating set from the Giraud axioms, you get what's sometimes called an [infinitary pretopos](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/pretopos#infinitary). You no longer have subobject classifiers, for instance. It's a different concept, but sometimes useful to consider. I'm not sure what to make of your question -- what are $A$, $B$, and $B^A$? I originally thought you meant $B^A$ to be the functor category between categories $A,B$; I've explained why the functor category is not so relevant when $A,B$ are toposes.

Comment: If you mean $A,B$ to be the object classes of topoes, and $B^A$ to be the conglomerate of functions between them, then again, usually one is interested in much smaller sub-classes of this conglomerate. If you mean $A,B$ to be _literally_ the sets representing the categories $A,B$ as encoded in ZFC using various ordered pair constructions, etc., and if you mean $B^A$ to be the conglomerate of functions, then I'm even more confused as to why you'd care about the construction $B^A$.

Comment: By $A$ and $B$ I mean the object classes. "usually one is interested in much smaller sub-classes of this conglomerate" If $E$ and $F$ are Grothendieck toposes, is the conglomerate of geometric/logical morphisms $E\to F$ a *class*?

Comment: Why are there no subobject classifiers anymore by dropping the small generating set? The "small generating set" condition seems to be just a technical, set-theoretical condition which limits the size of toposes. I am curious how such a technical set-theoretical condition has real implications such as the existence of subobject classifiers.

Comment: @user1009651 If $E$ and $F$ are Grothendieck toposes, then the conglomerate of geometric morphisms $E \to F$ is at least in bijection with a class (thought it may not technically be a class, I'm not sure). In fact, the larger conglomerate of all [accessible functors](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/accessible+functor) $E \to F$ is in bijection with a class, because each accessible functor between accessible categories is determined up to isomorphism by what it does on a small subcategory, and the isomorphism classes of accessible functors are also class-sized.

Comment: I'm sure there's a construction of the subobject classifier from the Giraud axioms in, say, MacLane and Moerdijk's book "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic", or in either of Johnstone's books "Topos Theory" and "Sketches of an Elephant". I want to say that it boils down to an adjoint-functor-theorem type argument. In any event, size restriction axioms are very often at their most powerful when they can be combined with the adjoint functor theorem. If you're interested in this sort of thing more generally maybe try Adamek and Rosicky's "Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories".

Comment: In fact, I think the Giraud axioms minus the size axiom don't even imply that your pretopos is cartesian closed -- you need some adjoint functor theorem - type argument for this.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very enlightening!